# onclick JavaScript button in image description not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, contact-form-7, image-gallery

I am using  and I want abutton below each image with an onclick JavaScript event, but it's not working if you insert it as an image description.

Why? It is working if it's inserted just in page, but not if in an image description. Here, only popup `class='popmake-4415'` works.

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    document.getElementById('mans').innerText = clicked_id;
}
```

Here `'mans'` is the `id` for field in Contact form 7

```html
<button class='popmake-4415' id="sarkans" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
```

I'm using Nexgen Gallery or GMedia gallery and [Contact form 7 plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) with WordPress. Different images will have different `id`. Is it possible to somehow fix this?

Comment: are you sure your button is clickable?  If another (transparent) element is drawn over it, it will never be accessible to the mouse.